# I want to add call function in my android app.but my code is not working

Tags: android

I want to add call function in my app.but my code is not working please guide me.When i try to run this code.My application crashes but it does not give any error....
My Code is here

```
public class ContactUs extends Fragment {
    final ContactUs context = this;
    Button button;
    String sNum;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_us,null);

        button = (Button) v. findViewById(R.id.tvCall);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                //         sNum = numTxt.getText().toString();
                if(sNum.trim().isEmpty()){
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
                } else{ i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+sNum));
                }
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please grant the permission to call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); requestPermission();
                }
                else { startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            private void requestPermission()
            { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1);
            }

        });

        return v;
    }
```

I also enter permissions in my menifest file.my manifest file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.amibank">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have corresponding buttons and xml files with such ids? Maybe try to remove @Nullable, then run your code and see if locat displays any  error messages.

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: If the application crashes, there would be a logcat. Make sure you don't have any filters on it, making it invisible to see.

Comment: thanks @HonorLT for giving suggestion to get error

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...Problem is there that it returns null on the sNum Variable.Actually there is no numText widget.When i comment it, it is working..

```
    public class ContactUs extends Fragment {
//    final ContactUs context = this;
    Button button;
    String sNum;
//    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_us,null);

        button = (Button) v. findViewById(R.id.tvCall);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                //         sNum = numTxt.getText().toString();
                //if(sNum.trim().isEmpty()){
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
               // } //else{ i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+sNum));
//                }
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please grant the permission to call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); requestPermission();
                }
                else { startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            private void requestPermission()
            { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1);
            }

        });

        return v;
    }
```